# append a value to existing url in reactjs

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, react-native

I have the following url and a parameter :

```
number:200
"http://localhost:8000/textpath"
```

I want the path to be like this:

```
"http://localhost:8000/textpath/200"
```

How do I do that using Reactjs?I want to use the appended url in fetch method as follows:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/textpath/200")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Template literals.

```
const url = `http://localhost:8000/textpath/${number}`    
fetch(url);
```

where number = 200

Refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more information

Comment: try assigning to a variable and then using it @Tim

Answer (score 0):

A simple append did the work.Doesn't have to complicate

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/textpath/"+number)
```